# How can I search a word on JSON format?

Tags: java, json

My JSON contains:

```
{"state":1,"employee":{"user":"raparra","pass":"1234","work":"taxy_driver"}}
```

I want to extract the pass (1234). Is there any function to make it easy and fast?  Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html I think this might be what you are looking for.

Comment: take a look at [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON parser with JsonPath support - it will find and extract only required data that are defined by a query.